# Why does opencv3 not support Python 3.7?

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I recently installed opencv3 for python 3.7 using brew install opencv@3, but the cv2.imread function doesn't work at all (no built in function, apparently)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Think you have the wrong package / module name try : opencv-python

source : https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/